# How to sort divs alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

The following code sorts the first word of the panel title alphabetically, but I would like it to extend to also sort the remaining words of the title (not just the first). How would I accomplish this? Thank you

```
 <!--HTML-->
<div class='col-md-3'>    
  <div class='panel panel-default drop-shadow'>
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">ABC 123</a></h3>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-body text-center'>
      <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
     Footer verbiage here
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-3'>    
  <div class='panel panel-default drop-shadow'>
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">ABC 456</a></h3>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-body text-center'>
      <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
     Footer verbiage here
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


//JS - Alpha Sort ASC
$('#alphaLinkAsc').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find(".panel-title").text() > $(b).find(".panel-title").text();
    });
    $(".filterList").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include some HTML so I can JSFiddle this up?

Comment: Although jQuery *happens* to contain a `sort` function in its prototype, `sort` is **not** part of the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/). If you want to reorder items, you'll need to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I added the HTML. I based my code off this JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` is only able to applied to an array.

You need to make sure that you get all of the divs into an Array before the sort method will work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Where is `$div` being assigned at? Can you confirm it's of type Array?